# Why the optimization of convex function (least squares with $ {L}^{1}$ regularization) does not converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I am trying to find the best `x` which fits $Ax=B$ and by this aim I am using the following cost function.

> $$\min\|Ax-B\|_2+\beta\|x\|_1$$

but when I use `optim()` function in R for optimization, it converges in a bad point which is not at least near the point (`x = psudoinverse(A)*B`).
I can initialize the `x` by this answer to get better result but I want to know the reason of not converging because the cost function is convex and it have to converge.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. PLease use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "the" best fit does not exist in the absolute. It is always relative to the norm(s) you use. it is "the best fit in the sense of". As you are referring to the pseudo inverse, it looks like you are looking for the best fit **in the least squares sense** Thus the less you can do (I am note sure it will converge) is to use all the time **squared** quadratic norms, for example under the form: $\min\|Ax-B\|_2^2+\beta\|x\|_2^2.$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks a lot. I will test the form which you have suggested. but I wanted to know the reasonable cause of this. Because when the function is convex, If we gradually go by the slip of it, we should find the minima, but in this situation, I could not. I guess this is because of that the function is not strict convex but I am not sure.

Comment: My little experience in optimization has convinced me that even a slight modification of the function to be minimized can lead to huge moves of  the "pocket" in which the iteration processes converges...

Comment: Isn't the `optimize()` function in R suited only for one-dimensional optimization?

Comment: @Alex I corrected it, I used optim(). It was a writing mistake.

Comment: I believe none of the optimization methods used by the `optim()` function will work for your problem. It seems that all of them rely on the fact that the function is smooth (including Nedler-Mead, though it does not require computing derivatives).

Comment: The proper solution, of course, is not to write your own solver. There are several R packages that will solve this problem for you.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks a lot. could you please suggest one of them?

Comment: lars, glmnet, genlasso...

Comment: Alex below pointed out this is not the true LASSO. But it does trace the same tradeoff curve if that is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `optim()` function will not solve your problem, since it is non-smooth (there are points where the derivative do not exist). The algorithms used by `optim()` rely on the on smoothness of the objective function. However, your problem is equivalent to an SOCP:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x, s \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in \mathbb{R}} &\quad t + \beta \sum_{i=1}^n s_i \\
\text{s.t.} 
 &\quad ||Ax - B||_2 \leq t \\
 &\quad x_i - s_i \leq 0 &\quad i = 1, \dots, n\\
 &\quad -x_i -s_i \leq 0 &\quad i = 1, \dots, n
\end{aligned}
$$
The last two constraints come from the reformulation of $|x_i| \leq s_i$ as $-s_i \leq x_i \leq s_i$, and splitting into two linear inequalities.

Now, you can use an SOCP solver, such as the `socp` function in CLSOCP package to solve your problem.

Comment: SOCP is total overkill for the LASSO. There are already several packages that solve it directly with more efficient methods.

Comment: This is not Lasso to the best of my knowledge. Note that the two norm is *not* squared. I am not aware of a solver in R for this specific problem.

Comment: Good point, you are right!

Comment: @Alex Thanks a lot. I will test it and report the result.

Answer (score 1):

According to R's documentation the function you mention, [`optimize()`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Optimization), only support 1D function.

Moreover, pay attention the LASSO Problem you're trying to minimize isn't smooth.
Hence you can't use method which assumes the objective function is smooth.

Comment: Thanks a lot. First, optimize() was a writing mistake, I correct it. It was optim(). Second, you mean it is not convex too? if I use $$\min\|Ax-B\|_2+\beta\|x\|_2$$, is the smoothness okay? I use this too, but it does not converge too.

Comment: Both are convex. Both aren't smooth :-). If you want something smooth use $ \arg \min_{x} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \beta \left\| x  \right\|_{2}^{2} $. Yet I must say that it is see to solve nay other of the two as there are solvers which can handle their non smoothness.